# C# Passing struct without copying it to async function

Tags: c#, struct, async-await

I want to prevent the struct from being copied.

Is there a workaround?

```cs
unsafe struct Buffer
{
    public fixed byte buffer[40960000]; // big size buffer, sample
}

class Reader
{
    Reader()
    {
        var data = new Buffer();
        Read(ref data);     // <- No Copy, but not asynchronous.
        ReadAsync(data);    // <- Copy..
     // ReadAsync(ref data) <- impossible. but need.
    }

    void Read(ref Buffer data)
    {
        // Need asynchronous.
    }

    async void ReadAsync(Buffer data)
    {
        // Poor efficiency.
    }
}
```

This is code similar to my situation.

I want to efficiently handle structs that take up a lot of memory.

Comment: Is it important that you're using a struct? Otherwise just switch to a class.

Comment: @Shawn You have to deal with large data that needs fast speed, so you have to use struct. The project is already big, so I can't change it.

Comment: If you cant use a class, how is your struct really built ? Is it coming from p/invoke ? Why not passing around pointers to a pinned version of this struct, given that you are in unsafe mode ?

Comment: @Olivier It doesn't actually use unsafe, it's written as an example to make the struct look huge.

Comment: Ok. Is copying once an option ?  (like wrapping the struct in a tuple class) Or you're looking for a zero-copy answer ?

Comment: General remark: huge structs are *not* a good design idea... its bad for performance, and you could easily hit a StackOverflowException (given that structs are allocated on the stack), which causes the program to crash without warning. Without much benefits.

Comment: @Olivier Blocking functions are being changed to asynchronous functions.
So, if you accept the copy, you will incur a large cost overall.

.. Switching the system from struct to class is risky because I did not design it.

Comment: Well, i'm affraid that without unsafe, without copy, and without refactoring to a class, there is not much you could do...
Moreover, passing around a struct using ref is equivalent to passing a class around (unless there is P/Invoke involved somewhere). The only difference is that the object memory lies on the stack instead of the heap. So that does not sound like a risky refactoring to me (unless P/invoke, again)

Comment: @Olivier Moving managed data from the stack to the heap is stable, but it can hurt performance.
 
Although the project is not small, it is not the code that understands all parts in-depth, so we want to make the minimal changes.

Comment: Can you not implement ReadAsync with a ref parameter? `ReadAsync ( ref Buffer buffer ) { original code }` and `ReadAsync ( Buffer buffer ) => ReadAsync( ref buffer );`